# TensorFlow: Labeling summary images with filenames

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a CNN to learn an unusual task where the labels for each image depend on the other images in the minibatch. Further, the data undergo a number of transformations and through a bunch of different threads and queues before the net can actually axes them.

I'd like to be able to validate that the label and image mapping is correct. However, it doesn't seem like it's possible to get TensorFlow to surface the filename for each image summary as part of [`tf.image_summary(...)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#image_summary). Does anyone know if it's possible to do this? Because the labeling regime is so unusual, you cannot gather immediately from the image if the label itself is correct. I need to be able to get the filename to recover the label properly. I can provide the filenames along with the images themselves and their labels in the queue without any problem.

Edit: To clarify, I'm using TensorBoard to display the image summaries.

Comment: if I want to debug things like that, I put the inputs/labels into the sess.run part that runs the optimizer, and use matplotlib to display images along with labels

Comment: Yeah, I could. I'd rather do it in in the context of Tensorflow, since it'll involve making tensorflow return it from the GPUs that are handling the bulk of the computation, which will likely slow things down. But I'm going to implement a single-GPU version of it and have it return everything every iteration so I can figure out what the hell is going on.